# Seg fault in C code with libtrace

Tags: c

I write this code using libtrace but I got segmentation fault. I put all of my code here for clarification. anyone can help me where is the problem!
I also should mention that the code want to sample some special packets base of the square coefficient.

```
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    while(trace_read_packet(trace,packet)> 0 ){
            if (filter && !trace_apply_filter(filter,packet))
                continue;
            if (packet->type < TRACE_RT_DATA_SIMPLE)
                /* Ignore RT messages */
                continue;
                numpackets ++;
            if (flag == true)
            {
                first =trace_get_seconds(packet);
                flag = false;
            }
            sizes[i] = trace_get_capture_length(packet);
            i++;
            randnumber = (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
            if(randnumber <= probability)
            {
                    //trace_dump_packet(packet);
            trace_write_packet(output, packet);
            sampledpackets++;
            }
            next = trace_get_seconds(packet);
            if (double_t(next - first)== blocktime)
            {
                scv = var(sizes, i);
                scv = a_scv * scv + scv_error;
                m = a_m * m + m_error;
                n = 1 - (n/2);
                probability = (ltqnorm(n)*e*scv) / m;
                i =0;
                flag = true;
            }

        }

        printf("\n");
        printf("number of packets is : %llu\n",numpackets);
        printf("number of sampled packet: %llu\n",sampledpackets);

        if (trace_is_err(trace)) {
            trace_perror(trace, "trace_read_packet");
        }
        trace_destroy(trace);
        trace_destroy_output(output);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, this is my memory output:

```
7fff18b1b000-7fff18b3c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 [stack]
7fff18bfe000-7fff18c00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 [vsyscall]
```

Comment: Where are any of your variables declared?

Comment: in the main but i have not put it here

Comment: Try compiling with `-Wall -g` and running it through [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html).

Comment: how can I do that? I use geany and use make to compile it

Comment: You could try debugging it by running it in a debugger.  Just a thought.....

Comment: but how can I debug it in Ubuntu??

Comment: What line is the segfault happening?

Comment: my problem is that I can not to find which line is the cause of segdault

Comment: @user3120628 "but how can I debug it in Ubuntu??" Ever heard of gdb?

Comment: The two most likely reasons why your code would segfault are 1) `packet` is an invalid pointer, or 2) `i` is out of bounds in the `sizes` array. (It would be helpful if you showed the variable declarations btw)

Comment: this is my variables:  struct libtrace_t *trace = NULL;
 libtrace_out_t *output = NULL;
 struct libtrace_packet_t *packet = trace_create_packet();
 struct libtrace_filter_t *filter=NULL;
 uint64_t numpackets=0;
 uint64_t sampledpackets=0;
 double randnumber;
 double_t first, next;
 bool flag = true;
 size_t sizes[N];
 uint64_t count=0;
 uint32_t i =0;
 double probability = 0.7;
 double scv = 0;
 uint32_t m =1;

Comment: and these are my parameters: uint64_t N = 50000;
double n = 0.1;
double e = 0.1;
double scv_error = 0.3;
double m_error = 0.3;
double a_m = 0.4;
double a_scv= 0.3;

Comment: i add some code to check size of array and i am sure that packet pointer is true but still i have segfault!

Comment: `gcc -Wall -g -o name_of_executable name_of_input.c` 
and then use a debugger on the executable - either `gdb` (should be on your system already) or Valgrind.  Google them if you need a primer on how to use them.

Comment: @user3120628  update your post, rather than comment, with your variable declarations.

Comment: `printf("number of packets is : %llu\n",numpackets);` may not match `uint64_t numpackets=0`.  Use `unsigned long long numpackets=0` or `printf("number of packets is : %" PRIu64 "\n",numpackets);`

Comment: `libtrace_out_t` is not defined.  `N` `TRACE_RT_DATA_SIMPLE`, `blocktime` not defined.

Comment: uint64_t N = 50000;
double n = 0.1;
double e = 0.1;
double scv_error = 0.3;
double m_error = 0.3;
double a_m = 0.4;
double a_scv= 0.3;

Comment: these are other parameters const double blocktime = 2.000000;
char ipaddress[20];

Answer (score 0):

libtrace requires you to call trace_create() and trace_create_output() before you can use them to read and write packets.  You might be doing this in the code you elided but I can't tell.

Comparing packet end-start times against a specific number will almost never be true, so you might overflow your sizes array.  I'd recommend using >= blocktime.

I'd suggest running this under gdb and looking at the backtrace and variables to see what's going on. try "gdb --args ./your-program foo.pcap" "run" then when it crashes "bt full".

As minor niggly points: I'd recommend using "trace_config(trace, TRACE_OPTION_FILTER, filter)" before your loop instead of calling trace_apply_filter on each packet, as libtrace can then then perhaps optimise this by, for example, pushing the bpf filter into the kernel.